# convert value to variable in R

Tags: r, for-loop

Say I have the following R code:

```
data(iris)

var<-c("mean","median")
ddf<-data.frame(var)

for (i in levels(iris$Species)) {
  i<-c(mean(iris$Sepal.Length),median(iris$Sepal.Length))
  ddf<-cbind(ddf,i)
}
```

which produces:

```
     var        i        i        i
1   mean 5.843333 5.843333 5.843333
2 median 5.800000 5.800000 5.800000
```

How can I make R return the names of the Species in the column names instead of the name of the variable `i`?

Essentially, how can I transform the value that was assigned to variable `i` into a variable itself?

PS.: I know I could more easily do the task above with dplyr, etc. But I really need to be able to do it this in a for loop.

Comment: `aggregate(Sepal.Length ~ Species, data=iris, FUN=function(x) c(mean=mean(x), med=median(x)))`. It is not clear from your question why you ***really need to be able to do this in a for loop***

Comment: Or use `dplyr`? `iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarize(mean = mean(Sepal.Length), median = median(Sepal.Length))`

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to get this, @jogo showed a nice solution with `aggregate`, here another in so-called "tidyverse" style:

```
library("dplyr")
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarize(mean=mean(Sepal.Length), median=median(Sepal.Length))
```

Loops are allowed, but often not necessary in R.

Answer (score 0):

An option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(iris)[, .(Mean = mean(Sepal.Length), 
          Median = median(Sepal.Length)), by = Species]
```